# Must a certain continued fraction have "small" partial quotients?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, pell-type-equations

I have reformulated the original question, which appears at the bottom, it a way that seems more likely to produce a reference.

New version: Let $\Delta$ be a positive nonsquare integer congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.  If $\Delta$ is even, expand $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}$ in a simple continued fraction.  If $\Delta$ is odd, expand $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}+1}{2}$ in a simple continued fraction.  Let $m$ be the greatest integer with $m \equiv \Delta \pmod{2}$ and $m^2 < \Delta$. Is the following claim true?

Claim: The continued fraction expansion consists of $\left\lceil \frac{m}{2} \right\rceil$ followed by a purely periodic sequence.  The repeating block has final quotient $m$, but all other quotients do not exceed $\frac{m}{2}$.

What surprises me is the bound on the other quotients.  When $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ has large fundamental unit, the repeating block will either need to be long or contain some big quotients.  It seems something is forcing the quotients to stay small, putting everything into the length instead.

Is it known if the claim always holds?  Is there a proof somewhere?

** Original post follows: **  Let $(t,u)$ be the fundamental solution to the Pellian equation (when solvable):  $t^2 - \Delta u^2 = -4$.  Otherwise, let $(t,u)$ be the fundamental solution to $t^2 - \Delta u^2 = 4$.  Data shows that these solutions can fluctuate quite wildly, and some can be "very large" in some sense compared to $\Delta$.

Set $r = \frac{t-u}{2u}$ if $\Delta$ is odd and $r = \frac{t}{2u}$ if $\Delta$ is even.  Expand $r$ in the simple continued fraction with an odd number of quotients if $t^2 - \Delta u^2 = -4$ was solvable and with an even number of partial quotients otherwise.  Using the theorem of Hermite and Serret, it can be shown that after dropping the first partial quotient, the remaining ones form a symmetric sequence.  What surprises me is the following observation, which I have found to hold numerically for small discriminants:

Observation:
Let $m$ be the greatest integer with $m \equiv \Delta \pmod{2}$ and $m^2 < \Delta$.  Then the partial quotients of the continued fraction expansion of $r$ do not exceed $m/2$.

An example:  when $\Delta = 193$, the equation $t^2 - 193 u^2 = -4$ is solvable with fundamental solution $(t,u) = (3528264,253970)$.  Also, $m = 13$, and $r = 1637147/253970$.  The continued fraction expansion has partial quotients $(6,2,4,6,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,6,4,2)$, which are all less than or equal to $m/2$.

The observation surprised me because when $t$ and $u$ swing up to large values,   $r$ can be quite large.  There seems to be something forcing the continued fraction toward having great length rather than large partial quotients.

Is it known if the observation always holds?  Is there a proof somewhere?

Comment: i get 1764132^2 - 193 * 126985^2 = -1.  Maybe you should check your $(t,u).$ If you are finding that with continued fractions, mistakes can happen. The method I use is due, largely, to Lagrange, and does not depend on decimal accuracy. Meanwhile, given prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there is always a solution to $x^2 - p y^2 = -1.$ Given another prime $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ as long as $p,q$ are mutual quadratic non-residues, there is a solution to $x^2 - pq y^2 = -1.$ If $p,q$ are mutual residues, it is not certain, the first failure is $205 = 5 \cdot 41,$ there is no $x^2 - 205 y^2 = -1.$

Comment: But I am using the Pellian equation $t^2 - \Delta u^2 = \pm 4$, not $t^2 - \Delta u^2 = \pm 1$.  When the $t$ and $u$ for $t^2 - \Delta u^2 = \pm 4$ are both even, as happens with $\Delta = 193$, then the $t$ and $u$ for the usual $t^2 - \Delta u^2 = \pm 1$ are just scaled down by a factor of $2$.  The quotient $r$ is then the same using either type of equation and the observation still holds.  But, for instance, with $\Delta = 124$, the fundamental solution of $t^2 - 124u^2 = 4$ is much smaller than that of $t^2 - 124u^2 = 1$, and tweaking the observation is harder.

Comment: In other words, it seems to be something about the fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$.  If $\Delta$ is a field discriminant, we can rephrase the observation by saying, if $a + b \sqrt{\Delta}$ is the fundamental unit, then $r=\tfrac{a-b}{2b}$ fits the observation.  Switching to Pellian equations, solutions of the equation $t^2 - 124u^2 = 1$ miss the fundamental unit $\tfrac{3040 + 273\sqrt{124}}{2}$, so I use $t^2 - 124u^2 = 4$ instead.

Comment: alright, first step gp-pari ? 3528264^2 - 193 * 253970^2 
%1 = -4
Next you seem to be taking $r = (1/2) (t/u) - (1/2),$ which is the reason you get the numerator as 1637147 rather than  1764132

Comment: Yes, since $\Delta$ is odd, I defined $r$ to be $\tfrac{t-u}{2u}$, which is $(1/2) (t/u) - 1/2$.  The observation concerns the continued fraction of $r$ defined in this way.

Comment: Barry, there is a simple theorem for the Lagrange Gauss reduced forms, that any number primitively represented by the form, with absolute value below an explicit bound, occurs as the first coefficient of a form in the chain of equivalent reduced forms. Do Zagier's forms do that for small positive values? I found my program for Zagier reduced form cycles, fixed it up a bit today. Good start.

Comment: @WillJagy One can modify an argument of Zagier to show that the smallest positive value represented by a class shows up as the first coefficient of some form reduced in the sense of Zagier.  From a little bit of computation, I expect the more general statement you mention is true.  Do you have a reference for that theorem for Gauss reduction?

Comment: for indefinite binaries this is Theorem 85 on page 111 of Dickson's Introduction to the Theory of Numbers (1929). I'm looking at the pages i copied from Zagier, 120-132.  The analogous result you want would begin with Dickson Theorem 84 on page 108, that two equivalent, reduced forms do belong to the same cycle. Probably stated in Zagier for his version... Keeping track of the coefficients provides a matrix in $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ that transforms $f$ into the new $g.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon = \Delta \mod 2 \in \{0 ; 1\}$ and $t = \frac 12 (\sqrt \Delta +\epsilon)$. $t$ is a quadratic algebraic number and it satisfies the equation $t^2 - \epsilon t - \frac 14(\Delta-\epsilon)$.

Consider $t$ together with his conjugate $\overline t < 0$ (because $\Delta>1$) and look at what happens during the continued fraction process.

If $(t,\overline t$) are solutions to equations of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $ac =a^2t\overline t<0$ and $b^2-4ac = a^2(t-\overline t)^2 = \Delta$,

then when you shift them by $k = \lfloor t \rfloor$, this has the effect of replacing $b$ with $b+2ka$ and $c$ with $ak^2+bk+c$. But since $t$ stays positive, and $\overline t$ gets even more negative, $t\overline t$ stays negative and so the new $ac$ is still negative ; and of course $a$ doesn't change and so neither does $\Delta$.

If $t<1$ and you take their reciprocal, this simply switches $a$ with $c$, and you still have $ac<0$ and $b^2-4ac = \Delta$. Also you can multiply $a,b,c$ by $-1$ at this point so we can only look at equations with $a>0$ and $c<0$.

Therefore during this whole process the triplets $(a,b,c)$ you "visit" all satisfy $a>0, c<0$ and $b^2 = \Delta + 4ac < \Delta$, so you can only visit a finite number of them before getting into a loop at some point.

Now, more importantly you are asking about the largest shift operation you can do. Obviously, $k = \lfloor t \rfloor \le t \le t - \overline{t}$, and since $(t - \overline t)^2 = \Delta/a^2$, the largest shifts are bound by $\sqrt \Delta / a $.

The worst case is when $a=1$ and your starting points are right in the middle of this family (they are at $b= -\epsilon $), so the shift length there should be around $\sqrt D/2$.
Eventually when you finish the loop, you end up at one of its extremities where $b$ is the biggest negative integer possible, that is $x^2-mx-\frac 14(\Delta-m^2)$ where $m$ is the largest positive integer such that $m^2 < \Delta$ and $4$ divides $\Delta-m^2$ (so this coincides with your $m$). When you do this shift completely, the length is $\lfloor t \rfloor = \lfloor \frac 12 (m+\sqrt \Delta) \rfloor = m$ (because $m \le \sqrt \Delta < m+2$).

For the sake of completeness, it takes $(m-\epsilon)/2$ steps to get from $b=-m$ to $b=-\epsilon$ (your starting point), which leaves a length of $(m+\epsilon)/2 = \lceil \frac m2 \rceil$ for the starting point.

The next worst case is when $a=2$, specifically when $b$ is the biggest negative possible, so for the roots of $2x^2-nx - \frac 18(\Delta-n^2)$ where $n$ is the largest positive integer less than $\sqrt D$ such that $8$ divides $\Delta-n^2$.
Here, $k= \lfloor t \rfloor = \lfloor \frac 14(n+\sqrt \Delta) \rfloor$.

If $\Delta = 1 \mod 8$ then $n=m$ and so you get $k=\lfloor \frac 12 \lfloor \frac 12(m+\sqrt \Delta) \rfloor \rfloor = \lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor$.
If $\Delta = 0 \mod 4$ then $n=m$ or $n=m-2$ (whichever is a multiple of $4$). In the second case, $k = \lfloor \frac {m-1}2 \rfloor = \lfloor \frac m 2 \rfloor - 1$.
If $\Delta = 5 \mod 8$ then you cannot reach a triplet with $a=2$ anyway.

Comment: Thank you! It certainly helped to reformulate in terms of quadratic irrationalities!  It is nice to see that definite bound on $b$, and then $a$ and $c$, that proves the periodicity is also what forces the quotients to stay small.  Also I appreciate the very thorough explanation of the other points in the claim.  I always think in terms of finite continued fractions, and often you can do the same stuff as with infinite ones.  Here is a good example that shows this is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Mercio has answered enough... meanwhile, I am getting a better idea of what you want: here is the Lagrange method for finding the cycle of neighboring reduced forms in the $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ of $x^2 + xy - 48 y^2.$ Look at the absolute values of my "delta" numbers at the right of each line, these are the partial quotients in a continued fraction.

EDIT:  found the thing you want, in my language. A Lagrange reduced form is $a x^2 + b xy + c y^2,$ or $\langle a,b,c \rangle,$ when $ac < 0$ and $b > |a+c|.$ Meanwhile the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac.$ We see that $0 < b < \sqrt \Delta.$ The number I call $\delta,$ which tells us how to get the right-neighboring form, is defined by $\delta C > 0$ and 
$$   |\delta| = \left\lfloor \; \left| \frac{b + \sqrt \Delta}{2c} \right| \;  \right\rfloor  $$
Given $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and the correct $\delta,$ the right-neighboring form is
$$  \langle \; c, \; -b + 2 c \delta, \; a - b \delta + c \delta^2 \; \rangle $$
As long as $c \neq \pm 1,$ we have $|c| \geq 2,$ and
$$ \color{blue}{ |\delta| < \frac{\sqrt \Delta}{2} }  $$

```
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 1 1 -48

  0  form              1           1         -48  delta      0
  1  form            -48          -1           1  delta      6
  2  form              1          13          -6


          -1          -6
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1           6
           0          -1

0  form   1 13 -6   delta  -2     ambiguous  
1  form   -6 11 3   delta  4
2  form   3 13 -2   delta  -6
3  form   -2 11 9   delta  1
4  form   9 7 -4   delta  -2
5  form   -4 9 7   delta  1
6  form   7 5 -6   delta  -1
7  form   -6 7 6   delta  1
8  form   6 5 -7   delta  -1
9  form   -7 9 4   delta  2
10  form   4 7 -9   delta  -1
11  form   -9 11 2   delta  6
12  form   2 13 -3   delta  -4
13  form   -3 11 6   delta  2
14  form   6 13 -1   delta  -13
15  form   -1 13 6   delta  2     ambiguous            -1 composed with form zero  
16  form   6 11 -3   delta  -4
17  form   -3 13 2   delta  6
18  form   2 11 -9   delta  -1
19  form   -9 7 4   delta  2
20  form   4 9 -7   delta  -1
21  form   -7 5 6   delta  1
22  form   6 7 -6   delta  -1
23  form   -6 5 7   delta  1
24  form   7 9 -4   delta  -2
25  form   -4 7 9   delta  1
26  form   9 11 -2   delta  -6
27  form   -2 13 3   delta  4
28  form   3 11 -6   delta  -2
29  form   -6 13 1   delta  13
30  form   1 13 -6


  form   1 x^2  + 13 x y  -6 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 193 dSqrt 13  M_Ratio  169
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-399847574329  -5376439248480
-896073208080  -12048799279369
=========================================
```

Here is $1021,$ very large numbers, but $-4$ is primitively represented as $1021 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$:

```
Pell unit 
198723867690977573219668252231077415636351801801^2 - 1021 * 6219237759214762827187409503019432615976684540^2 = 1 

=========================================

Pell NEGATIVE 
315217280372584882515030^2 - 1021 * 9865001296666956406909^2 = -1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
7352358509351027^2 - 1021 * 230098509011235^2 = 4 

=========================================

  -4 PRIMITIVE 
85745895^2 - 1021 * 2683493^2 = -4 

=========================================

1021       1021

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 1 1 -255

  0  form              1           1        -255  delta      0
  1  form           -255          -1           1  delta     15
  2  form              1          31         -15


          -1         -15
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1          15
           0          -1

0  form   1 31 -15   delta  -2     ambiguous  
1  form   -15 29 3   delta  10
2  form   3 31 -5   delta  -6
3  form   -5 29 9   delta  3
4  form   9 25 -11   delta  -2
5  form   -11 19 15   delta  1
6  form   15 11 -15   delta  -1
7  form   -15 19 11   delta  2
8  form   11 25 -9   delta  -3
9  form   -9 29 5   delta  6
10  form   5 31 -3   delta  -10
11  form   -3 29 15   delta  2
12  form   15 31 -1   delta  -31
13  form   -1 31 15   delta  2     ambiguous            -1 composed with form zero  
14  form   15 29 -3   delta  -10
15  form   -3 31 5   delta  6
16  form   5 29 -9   delta  -3
17  form   -9 25 11   delta  2
18  form   11 19 -15   delta  -1
19  form   -15 11 15   delta  1
20  form   15 19 -11   delta  -2
21  form   -11 25 9   delta  3
22  form   9 29 -5   delta  -6
23  form   -5 31 3   delta  10
24  form   3 29 -15   delta  -2
25  form   -15 31 1   delta  31
26  form   1 31 -15


  form   1 x^2  + 31 x y  -15 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 1021 dSqrt 31  M_Ratio  961
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-109652365001371  -3451477635168525
-230098509011235  -7242706144349656
=========================================
```

---

Here is $1609 \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$ found it with https://oeis.org/A002350/b002350.txt  but your C.F. has very small digits except for the single pair of $\pm 39$

```
Pell unit 
106239618545424991765243316655636841919665809723452449^2 - 1609 * 2648551857407766364935405630459204820419664252354920^2 = 1 

=========================================

Pell NEGATIVE 
230477350888785807136105668^2 - 1609 * 5745796381280420432166845^2 = -1 

=========================================

1609       1609

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 1 1 -402

  0  form              1           1        -402  delta      0
  1  form           -402          -1           1  delta     19
  2  form              1          39         -22


          -1         -19
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1          19
           0          -1

0  form   1 39 -22   delta  -1     ambiguous  
1  form   -22 5 18   delta  1
2  form   18 31 -9   delta  -3
3  form   -9 23 30   delta  1
4  form   30 37 -2   delta  -19
5  form   -2 39 11   delta  3
6  form   11 27 -20   delta  -1
7  form   -20 13 18   delta  1
8  form   18 23 -15   delta  -2
9  form   -15 37 4   delta  9
10  form   4 35 -24   delta  -1
11  form   -24 13 15   delta  1
12  form   15 17 -22   delta  -1
13  form   -22 27 10   delta  3
14  form   10 33 -13   delta  -2
15  form   -13 19 24   delta  1
16  form   24 29 -8   delta  -4
17  form   -8 35 12   delta  3
18  form   12 37 -5   delta  -7
19  form   -5 33 26   delta  1
20  form   26 19 -12   delta  -2
21  form   -12 29 16   delta  2
22  form   16 35 -6   delta  -6
23  form   -6 37 10   delta  3
24  form   10 23 -27   delta  -1
25  form   -27 31 6   delta  5
26  form   6 29 -32   delta  -1
27  form   -32 35 3   delta  12
28  form   3 37 -20   delta  -1
29  form   -20 3 20   delta  1
30  form   20 37 -3   delta  -12
31  form   -3 35 32   delta  1
32  form   32 29 -6   delta  -5
33  form   -6 31 27   delta  1
34  form   27 23 -10   delta  -3
35  form   -10 37 6   delta  6
36  form   6 35 -16   delta  -2
37  form   -16 29 12   delta  2
38  form   12 19 -26   delta  -1
39  form   -26 33 5   delta  7
40  form   5 37 -12   delta  -3
41  form   -12 35 8   delta  4
42  form   8 29 -24   delta  -1
43  form   -24 19 13   delta  2
44  form   13 33 -10   delta  -3
45  form   -10 27 22   delta  1
46  form   22 17 -15   delta  -1
47  form   -15 13 24   delta  1
48  form   24 35 -4   delta  -9
49  form   -4 37 15   delta  2
50  form   15 23 -18   delta  -1
51  form   -18 13 20   delta  1
52  form   20 27 -11   delta  -3
53  form   -11 39 2   delta  19
54  form   2 37 -30   delta  -1
55  form   -30 23 9   delta  3
56  form   9 31 -18   delta  -1
57  form   -18 5 22   delta  1
58  form   22 39 -1   delta  -39
59  form   -1 39 22   delta  1     ambiguous            -1 composed with form zero  
60  form   22 5 -18   delta  -1
61  form   -18 31 9   delta  3
62  form   9 23 -30   delta  -1
63  form   -30 37 2   delta  19
64  form   2 39 -11   delta  -3
65  form   -11 27 20   delta  1
66  form   20 13 -18   delta  -1
67  form   -18 23 15   delta  2
68  form   15 37 -4   delta  -9
69  form   -4 35 24   delta  1
70  form   24 13 -15   delta  -1
71  form   -15 17 22   delta  1
72  form   22 27 -10   delta  -3
73  form   -10 33 13   delta  2
74  form   13 19 -24   delta  -1
75  form   -24 29 8   delta  4
76  form   8 35 -12   delta  -3
77  form   -12 37 5   delta  7
78  form   5 33 -26   delta  -1
79  form   -26 19 12   delta  2
80  form   12 29 -16   delta  -2
81  form   -16 35 6   delta  6
82  form   6 37 -10   delta  -3
83  form   -10 23 27   delta  1
84  form   27 31 -6   delta  -5
85  form   -6 29 32   delta  1
86  form   32 35 -3   delta  -12
87  form   -3 37 20   delta  1
88  form   20 3 -20   delta  -1
89  form   -20 37 3   delta  12
90  form   3 35 -32   delta  -1
91  form   -32 29 6   delta  5
92  form   6 31 -27   delta  -1
93  form   -27 23 10   delta  3
94  form   10 37 -6   delta  -6
95  form   -6 35 16   delta  2
96  form   16 29 -12   delta  -2
97  form   -12 19 26   delta  1
98  form   26 33 -5   delta  -7
99  form   -5 37 12   delta  3
100  form   12 35 -8   delta  -4
101  form   -8 29 24   delta  1
102  form   24 19 -13   delta  -2
103  form   -13 33 10   delta  3
104  form   10 27 -22   delta  -1
105  form   -22 17 15   delta  1
106  form   15 13 -24   delta  -1
107  form   -24 35 4   delta  9
108  form   4 37 -15   delta  -2
109  form   -15 23 18   delta  1
110  form   18 13 -20   delta  -1
111  form   -20 27 11   delta  3
112  form   11 39 -2   delta  -19
113  form   -2 37 30   delta  1
114  form   30 23 -9   delta  -3
115  form   -9 31 18   delta  1
116  form   18 5 -22   delta  -1
117  form   -22 39 1   delta  39
118  form   1 39 -22


  form   1 x^2  + 39 x y  -22 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 1609 dSqrt 40  M_Ratio  1600
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-2946096106522103532762497067727853923298903881610569  -116536281725941720057157847740205012098465227103616480
-5297103714815532729870811260918409640839328504709840  -209533140984327879997724136243545829916032715565294329
=========================================
```

---

Comment: Thanks.  This makes sense.  I, too, prefer the forms point of view.  But I am most familiar with Zagier's method, which in this context pushes me from simple continued fractions to negative ones. 

Tough to choose which answer to accept.  Mercio beat you to it, but only just barely.  They seem to be basically the same, but in different languages.  But it seems elegant to me that the condition just falls out of the reducing number like this.

However, Mercio's method thoroughly went through all of the points of the claim, and his bound is slightly better, like when $\Delta = 113$.

Comment: @BarrySmith just so you know, Lagrange's method and Zagier's differ in only the point you mention, continued fractions with + signs or continued fractions with - signs. Zagier's condition for reduced is $a>0, c>0, b>a+c.$ His $\delta$ uses the ceiling function instead of the floor; with a little work, you could write the whole business in exactly the way I do (I have programmed that). Compare: Lagrange, $ac<0,$ with $b > |a+c|.$ You do not really need the continued fractions; both processes are $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ acting on forms, one step at a time.

Comment: I am certain you are correct. I could now rewrite everything using Zagier reduction.  But the thing I was studying that produced the original question led to a simple continued fraction.  Zagier's method would seemingly be able to bound the quotients of a certain negative continued fraction.  That also seems interesting, but is not directly relevant to the investigations that inspired the question.  I should say, I am very appreciative of the feedback you have provided on this and other questions I have asked here, even if I accepted another answer in this instance.