# What is known about the average of the partial quotients in the fundamental period of continued fraction expansions?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, continued-fractions

My broad question is as in the title.

The motivation is the following: let $\Delta$ be a positive, nonsquare integer congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. Set $\varepsilon = 1$ if $\Delta$ is odd and $\varepsilon = 0$ if $\Delta$ is even.  An earlier post

[Must a certain continued fraction have "small" partial quotients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861773/must-a-certain-continued-fraction-have-small-partial-quotients)

shows that the partial quotients of the fundamental period when expanding $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}+\varepsilon}{2}$ in a continued fraction are bounded above.

Computational evidence suggests that there is competing pressure from below.  For $\Delta < 100000$, the average the partial quotients in the fundamental period is $\geq 2$ except when $\Delta = 5$, $12$, $17$, or $28$, and it seems possible that these averages will eventually exceed any given bound.

So I would like to find results about averages over fundamental periods in the literature.   I am in particular looking for results about the quadratic irrationalities above, especially for a proof that they are above 2 outside of the exceptions I noted.  But I am also happy to see asymptotic or ineffective bounds or results for other sorts of quadratic irrationalities.

Comment: I'll go cross-post the conjecture below at MO

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252816/growth-rate-for-the-average-of-the-entries-in-the-fundamental-period-of-the-cont

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the meantime, developed a conjecture in the case where $\Delta$ is even.  In that case, $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}+\varepsilon}{2}$ is just $\sqrt{n}$ for $n = \Delta/4$.

**Conjecture:**  For each nonsquare positive integer $n$, let $a_n$ be the average of the entries of the fundamental period of $\sqrt{n}$.  Then

$$ a_n = \Omega(\ln n) $$

(using the Knuth definition of $\Omega$)

I have conducted a search through all $n$ between $2$ and $8 \times 10^7$.  The successive minima of $a_n/ln(n)$ over this range are as follows (with pairs $(n,a_n/ln(n))$

(2,2.885)

(3, 1.365)

(7, 0.899)

(13, 0.780)

(21, 0.766)

(44, 0.661)

(115, 0.653)

(190, 0.626)

(244, 0.602)

(397609, 0.600)

(811924, 0.598)

(940801, 0.595)

(4861081, 0.594)

(6868801, 0.593)

(11468521, 0.591)

(13981081, 0.590)

(70023409, 0.589)

Edit: the originally conjecture I gave was a classic example of overfitting.  Nevertheless, since I am interested in a lower bound on $a_n$, the data above made me concerned that in fact $a_n = o(\ln n)$, hence my reason for complicating the expression in the conjecture.  But a little bit of computation shows that data supports well the following weakening of the above conjecture: $a_n = \omega( \ln n / \ln (\ln n)^{\varepsilon})$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$.