# Partial quotients of continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, upper-lower-bounds

Are the partial quotients in the fundamental period of $\sqrt{p}$ for an odd prime $p$ are always less than $\sqrt{p}$ (apart from obviously the last entry which is two times the nearest integer to $\sqrt{p}$), i.e. if $\sqrt{p} = \langle{n; \overline{a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{r}}\rangle}$ where $a_{r} = 2n$, $n$ being the largest integer less than $\sqrt{p}$, then can $a_{i} > \sqrt{p}$ happen for any $i = 1,2,...,r-1$.

I was going through a list of continued fraction representation of $\sqrt{p}$ and it seemed the answer will be yes but could not find any result to back it up.

For example $\sqrt{19} = \langle{4; \overline{2,1,3,1,2,8}\rangle}$. None of the $a_{i} (\neq a_{6})$ is greater than $\sqrt{19}$.

$\sqrt{23} = \langle{4; \overline{1,3,1,8}\rangle}$. None of the $a_{i} (\neq a_{4})$ is greater than $\sqrt{23}$ again.

Comment: The Question doesn’t quite make sense in its present form.  We are not told what $p$ is.  Assuming it is a prime number, or at least a positive integer not a perfect square, then $\sqrt p$ is an irrational real number.  But this is not literally a continued fraction.  Every positive irrational number has a (unique) simple continued fraction, and in the case that $p$ is a positive integer not a perfect square, the terms are eventually periodic.  Perhaps you should work out an example to illustrate what you mean or suspect is true about the partial quotients in such a case.

Comment: Sorry for the not so precise formulation of the question. I have edited it now.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on periodic continued fractions attributes to Lagrange a result on bounding the [partial denominators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction#Length_of_the_repeating_block) by $2\sqrt{p}$, which is somewhat weaker than your idea.

Comment: I have edited again. Hope it helps this time. I gave two examples but I checked it works well for primes below 50.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems the answer to my original question is quite straight-forward from there whenever the denominator $Q_{n}$ is greater than $1$. The case $Q_{n} = 1$ will probably lead to the last term $a_{r}$ but I will check it. Thanks again.

Comment: See also this previous Question: [Must a certain continued fraction have "small" partial quotients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861773/must-a-certain-continued-fraction-have-small-partial-quotients)

Comment: Here’s what seems to be true (I thought once that I had complete proofs, but I haven’t seemed able to reproduce them): if $n<\sqrt m<n+1$ (no need for $m$ to be prime), then: aside from $2n$, which appears at the end of the periodic block, all partial quotients are $\le n$. Not only that, the p.q. $n$ can appear only in the middle of the periodic block (excluding the end number $2n$). I guess all of this has been known for 200 years.